# I can Inject my RepositoryClass in my NotificationService

Tags: android, dagger-2, intentservice, dagger, android-intentservice

I'm trying to Inject my ToDoRepository to my ToDoDeleteNotificationService and always I get this repository null. I don't know if I have to do another Module more or if I can't do it in a IntentService.

```
@Module
public class ToDoRepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ToDoDatabase provideDatabase(Application application) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(application,
            ToDoDatabase.class, "ToDo.db")
            .build();
    }

    @Provides
@Singleton
ToDoDao provideUserDao(ToDoDatabase database) {
    return database.toDoDao();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
AppExecutors provideAppExecutors() {
    return new AppExecutors();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
ToDoRepository providesToDoRepository(ToDoDao toDoDao, AppExecutors appExecutors) {
    return new ToDoRepository(toDoDao, appExecutors);
}
}
```

-- When my class TodoDeleteNotiricationService is called, I get my todoId byt my repository is null

```
public class ToDoDeleteNotificationService extends IntentService {
@Inject
ToDoRepository mToDoRepository;

public ToDoDeleteNotificationService() {
    super("ToDoDeleteNotificationService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    assert intent != null;
    String toDoId = intent.getStringExtra(ToDoNotificationsService.TODO_MODEL_KEY);
    mToDoRepository.deleteToDo(toDoId);
}
}
```

--

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ToDoRepositoryModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<ToDoApplication>{
    ToDoRepository getToDoRepository();

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        @BindsInstance
        AppComponent.Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need something in your Service class like, `DaggerComponent.build().inject(this)` or `mToDoRepository = DaggerComponent.build().getToDoRepository()`

Comment: I have solved the issue, I didn't remember put this in my module:

 @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    abstract ToDoDeleteNotificationService providesDeleteNotificationService();